# Using cURL to read, completing some steps, then posting

Tags: php, post, curl, authentication, readfile

Solved:
**Yay. In addition to what you wrote Drew, I found this: http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/07/24/maintaining-php-session-when-using-curl/
session_write_close(); before initializing the next set. Now I just need to figure out AJAX/jquery, because it looks like I can't register resource variables (e.g. Curl's handle) in a session.**

---

I want to login to a site using cURL. Their login process uses a token which I am able to parse using file_get_contents(). However, when I try to access the site again using cURL, the token is no longer good. Is there a way read the file using cURL, pause to do the calculations/steps, *and then* post the fields? Is there a better way?

Comment: `parse using file_get_contents` ??? I would really like to see that code

Comment: Alright. I parsed it after getting the file using file_get_contents. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is probably no longer good because it is associated with a session cookie that gets set when you access the site.  Since `file_get_contents` has no cookie tracking, you should use cURL to request the initial URL, grab the token, do your calculations, and then post back using cURL again.

To get cURL to keep track of the cookies, use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options for the cURL handle.

```
$cookies = '/tmp/cookies.txt';  // path to cookie file
$ch = curl_init('http://site.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
//...
$res = curl_exec($ch);

// grab token here...

// do calculations here...

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.com/next-url');

$res = curl_exec($ch); // execute next request on same handle
```

Here are some other answers of mine that use cURL to login to various websites and perform actions; looking at the code may be of help to you.

- [Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off/8992557#8992557)
- [PHP Curl - Cookies problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522149/php-curl-cookies-problem/7532730#7532730)
- [Trouble getting a list of cities from LS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548524/trouble-getting-a-list-of-cities-from-ls/7605146#7605146)
- [How to login in with Curl and SSL and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307744/how-to-login-in-with-curl-and-ssl-and-cookies/10307956#10307956)
- [How to make Curl post Using Php involving cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419185/how-to-make-curl-post-using-php-involving-cookies/11419912#11419912)
- [Retrieve Android Market mylibrary with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958495/retrieve-android-market-mylibrary-with-curl/8998077#8998077)
- [php cURL log into jsp website and return HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575419/php-curl-log-into-jsp-website-and-return-html/9576205#9576205)

Comment: I tried it, but no. Every time that page is refreshed, there is a new token.

Comment: Yeah a new token on each refresh makes sense, how are you sending it with the form?  The token is probably stored in a session based on some cookie.  Impossible to help without knowing the site and URL you are trying to log into or seeing some code that you have.

Comment: No. They store it as a value in their form. I just added my code.

Comment: Yeah they store the value in the form so the client can submit it, but if the token isn't also stored on the server side, then how can they validate the token?  I bet that if you clear your cookies and request the page you will see a cookie gets set.  The cookie is what ties your token to the one on the server.

Comment: They aren't checking the token. They're using it to encrypt the password and then checking that. I've tested (with help for Chrome's develop tools and Charles proxy), so I know I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your help so far. I didn't notice that you hadn't put in curl_close and then curl_init. I'm working on that now. Question: Do you know if it's possible to pass the $ch in the session cookies or should I just look into AJAX/jquery?